# ATtiny85 USB development board

Tags: attiny85

I am working on a project and have a custom PCB for the project. I initially developed the PCB to mount a DIP-8 ATtiny85.

[image: Photo of 8-pin DIP]

I then found the ATtiny85 is available in an SMD package, so I am thinking of changing the PCB to use the SMD version. But after I searched the local market in my country I did not find the SMD version; however, I found this board which has an ATtiny85 SMD:

[image: Photo of an SMD ATtiny85 on a PCB with other components]

Can I just upload the code to this board then desolder the SMD ATtiny85 and mount it on my PCB?

Comment: all images posted at this site require a link to the source of the image ... please update your question with the information ... **do not** write a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chip needs a bootloader to flash programs via USB. It might come already flashed with a bootloader, it might not (in which case you will need an AVR programmer or something like an arduino to emulate one). Other than that, yes, you can desolder the chip and use it after it's programmed via USB.

Comment: .. and before desoldering, make sure the correct fuse settings for the clock are set.

Comment: Yes i will use arduino uno as programmer, the usb here is just to power the board, so i will programm the board with arduino then desoldering the chip

Comment: @MiNiMe how i check that?, sorry i am need to bootloader

Comment: So if you can't program it over USB, you need to attach the pinstripe and do it there. Seems like a lot of trouble just to get the SMD variant. Why not use DIP?

Comment: @MiNiMe i do not know just realized attiny85 has a smd version so i thought it will be better to use smd one, it seems this will be so complex i will return to the DIP

Comment: Unless you are space constrained or going mass production, you will do fine using through hole components.

Comment: Other options include putting the programming points (with small pins or sockets) onto your design circuit, with that you may be able to program either chip type with wired jumpers going to a Arduino or an AVR programming board.  Another option is to buy a small SMD to DIP adapter, then including a DIP socket on the board would allow either chip type. Lastly you might design the board layout with the SMD pattern located under the dip pattern.

Comment: @MiNiMe if iam going to use the reset pin as input pin, will i still need to correct the fuse setting of this attiny85 development board?

Comment: The fuses set such important things as BoD, clock source, and to disable reset to use the pin as an IO. Clock source and reset is where you can screw up bad, if either of them are incorrect, you have locked yourself out of the chip and need a HV programmer to unbrick the chip.

Answer (score 2):

The ATtiny85 has no built-in USB. You can put a software emulation for low-speed USB on it. It's called V-USB. Maybe it has that preinstalled, maybe not.

But I think that USB connector is only for powering the board.